# Spec not allow body (remove in gpr file) without touching source files

Tags: ada, gnat

I got the following error which is common with generated sources:

> spec of this package does not allow a body

I would like to know if it exist a rule to put in the gpr file to ignore this error.
Like a ignore flag.

As I mentioned this files are generated so I have no right on them (not allowed to suppress them neither rewrite them).
More over it would be nice to have a rule that work for every generation.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to compile

```
package Guillaume is
end Guillaume;

package body Guillaume is
end Guillaume;
```

in Ada 1983 mode, you would get e.g.

```
gnatmake -gnat83 guillaume.ads
gcc -c -gnat83 guillaume.ads
guillaume.ada:1:09: warning: package "Guillaume" does not require a body
guillaume.ada:1:09: warning: body in file "guillaume.adb" will be ignored
```

Having a body that isn’t required by the spec was made illegal with Ada 95 (it would be possible to change a body and for the compilation process not to notice that it needed to be recompiled, leading to confusion). If your code generator was designed to produce Ada 83, then I guess you may have to face compiling in Ada 83 mode - but GNAT doesn’t, as far as I know, guarantee to be 100% compatible, particularly as far as the run time system is concerned.

Are the offending package bodies all actually empty? If so, you might be able to list them and use the `Excluded_Source_List_File` attribute in your project. If not, you are in trouble, because there’s no way (without changing package sources) to get the code in them to execute.

(Later): actually, `Excluded_Source_List_File` doesn’t help; it stops gprbuild looking at the file, but not the compiler; and it’s the compiler that rejects the body. Sorry. But if you could make such a list you could use it to delete the bad bodies.

Comment: Oh too bad... My sources are in Ada 95 and I can't change it (critical real time app). And the excluded files problem is that I need to know the files to exclude before create the gpr. Indeed these files are generated. The solution might only be to script the excluded files creation...

Comment: But yes the package not allowed are empty. Only contains comment

Comment: `Excluded_Source_List_File` takes the name of a file which contains a list of the files to be excluded - which you could create at each generation run, without changing the gpr.

Comment: `Excluded_Source_List_File` could not be put in the gpr file?

Comment: If a spec does not have neither a procedure nor a function declaration, the body shall not be used, as Simon mentioned. However, you can add `pragma Elaborate_Body` to the spec in your source code generation tool/script, if possible. The pragma is supported in Ada 95 on-wards and tells the compiler to elaborate (i.e., process) the body, even if the spec is "empty" w.r.t. to sub-programs.

Comment: See updated answer re: why `Excluded_Source_List_File` is no good.

Comment: The problem with `Excluded_Source_List_File` is that you need to know all the files that have an empty body at the compilation time. Whereas the compilation goes write after the genration. And the generation create this use less body. That's why I was looking for an option that purely ignore these body. 
Maybe modify the tool that create the body and add the `pragma Elaborate_Body` will do it. 
Sorry for not answering my internet was down.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the body from the list of source files:

```
for Excluded_Source_Files use ("my_body.adb");
```

Comment: This is kind of I was expecting. But does it exists like a flag (that ignore every time a spec doesn't allow a body?)

Comment: I could make a script that rewrite the gpr file after finding the file which doesn't allow a body (parse the compilation error for example). But isn't a very clean programming method.